# Inference in structured prediction

Tags: machine-learning, perceptron

When using `structured prediction`, part of the training phase includes estimating the value of y_hat, like this:

```
prediction ŷ = arg max {y ∈ GEN(x)} (w⊤ Φ(x, y))
```

How is this inference implemented, assuming that there is an exponential number of possible `y`'s that one would need to check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In many cases the exact inference problem is too hard to solve, so people use approximations like beam search to make it tractable.

See this paper by Huang et al. (2012) for more information (and a proof that structured perceptrons with inexact search still converge): http://www.aclweb.org/anthology/N12-1015
and the classical paper by Michael Collins:
http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~mcollins/papers/tagperc.pdf

Hope this helps.